# Is there a way to change the location of the wiper in circuitikz (default is middle)?

Tags: circuitikz

Here is the code. The defult one is always in the middle.

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}    
\usepackage[left=20mm,top=30mm,bottom=30mm,right=20mm]{geometry}

\usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz} % circuit package and  include electrical units in our labels


\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{circuitikz} [american voltages, longpot/.style = {pR, resistors/scale=0.75,
resistors/width=1.6, resistors/zigs=6}] \draw
  (5,0) to
  (5,3) to [V, v<=10<\volt>,  a = $V_{source}$] (-1,3) --
  (-1,0) -- (1,0) to [longpot, a^ =  \SI{10} {k\ohm}, mirror] (3,0) -- (5,0)
  
  (-1,0) --
  (-1,-2) to [R, a = \SI{10} {k\ohm}]  (2,-2) -- (2,-0.4)
\end{circuitikz}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

The document only mentions the rotation of wiper.

[image]

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](//tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See section 3.5.1 of the Circuitikz manual.  It shows how to use the wiper pos key to change the location of the wiper.

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}    
\usepackage[left=20mm,top=30mm,bottom=30mm,right=20mm]{geometry}

\usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz} % circuit package and  include electrical units in our labels


\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{circuitikz} [american voltages, longpot/.style = {pR, resistors/scale=0.75,
resistors/width=1.6, resistors/zigs=6}] \draw
  (5,0) to
  (5,3) to [V, v<=10<\volt>,  a = $V_{source}$] (-1,3) --
  (-1,0) -- (1,0) to [longpot, wiper pos=.2, a^ =  \SI{10} {k\ohm}, mirror, n=mypot] (3,0) -- (5,0)
  
  (-1,0) --
  (-1,-2) to [R, a = \SI{10} {k\ohm}]  (1,-2) -| (mypot.wiper);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `resistor` instead of `pR` and then draw the arrow at the end of the path. (I used `Stealth[width=3pt, inset=1pt]` for the arrow.

Note, I also changed your coordinates to relative coordinates using `++(x,y)` to specify the position relative to the previous coordinate. This makes adjustments easier. The coordinate `++(2.7,0)` near the end causes a shift to the right by 2.7cm from the previous coordinate. `++(3,0)` would have been your original.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}    
\usepackage[left=20mm,top=30mm,bottom=30mm,right=20mm]{geometry}

\usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz} % circuit package and  include electrical units in our labels


\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{circuitikz} [american voltages, longpot/.style = {resistor, resistors/scale=0.75, resistors/width=1.6, resistors/zigs=6}] 
  \draw[-{Stealth[width=3pt, inset=1pt]}] (5,0) to ++(0,3)
  to [V, v<=10<\volt>,  a = $V_{source}$] ++(-6,0) -- ++(0,-3) -- ++ (2,0)
  to [longpot, a^ =  \SI{10} {k\ohm}, mirror] ++(2,0) -- ++(2,0)
  
  ++(-6,0) -- ++(0,-2) to [R, a = \SI{10} {k\ohm}]  ++(2.7,0) -- ++(0,1.8);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is needed only for a (quite) old version of `circuitikz`, you have the `pos` key now...

Comment: @Rmano: It's true, but connecting the wiper arrow to the line requires some additional work—line width as well as the coordinate. I know, it's not hard to do, but why not just add the arrow to the end of the line?